# flot multiple graph do not zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, flot

right now i am using flot to plot graphs. the problem is when there is only one graph then everything works fine. but when there are more than one graph and i zoom. it only zooms the first one second one disappears. i have also check boxes from which i can select between the graphs when i select only second one then also zoom does not work.but if i select only first one then every thing is fine. it seems that zooming is only working with first graph. and when both graphs are there then only first one zooms second one entirely disappears

here is my code

```
 $(function() {
var datasets = new Array();
var data=[]
var optionsOverview = {
        legend: {show: false},
        series: {lines: {show: true,lineWidth: 1},shadowSize: 0},
        xaxis: {ticks: 5},
        yaxis: {ticks: 6},
        grid: {color: "#999"},
        selection: {mode: "xy"}
        }
var optionsDetail={
        yaxis: {axisLabel: "Voltage"},
        xaxis: {axisLabel: "Time in nano seconds"}, 
        points: {show: true}, 
        lines: {show: true,fill: false}, 
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true,color: "#999" }, 
        selection: { mode: "xy" },
        legend: {
                noColumns: 0,
                labelFormatter: function (label, series) {
                    return "<font color=\"white\">" + label + "</font>";
                },           
                backgroundColor: "#000",
                backgroundOpacity: 0.9,
                labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
                position: "ne"
                }
        }
    drawPlot();


    function drawPlot()
    {
        $.getJSON("test.json", function(json) { //test.json is the file which contains my data in json format
            datasets = json;
        //console.log(datasets);
        var i = 0;
        $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
            val.color = i;
            ++i;
        });

        // insert checkboxes 
        $("#resultChoices").empty();
        var plotDetail=null;
        var overview=null;

        var choiceContainer = $("#resultChoices");
        $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
            choiceContainer.append("<br/><input type='checkbox' name='" + key +
                "' checked='checked' id='id" + key + "'></input>" +
                "<label for='id" + key + "'>"
                + val.label + "</label>");
        });

        choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);
        $("#httpStatus").find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices); //find the button inside the main div and detect the click to plot everything

        function plotAccordingToChoices() 
        {
            data = [];
            choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
                var key = $(this).attr("name");
                if (key && datasets[key]) 
                {
                    data.push(datasets[key]);
                }
            });
                //if (data.length > 0) {
                plotDetail=$.plot("#resultHolder", data, optionsDetail);
                // Create the overview plot
                overview = $.plot("#resultOverview", data, optionsOverview);
        }       
        // now connect the two
        $("#resultHolder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
            //console.log(ranges);
            // clamp the zooming to prevent eternal zoom
            if (ranges.xaxis.to - ranges.xaxis.from < 0.00001) {
                ranges.xaxis.to = ranges.xaxis.from + 0.00001;
            }
            if (ranges.yaxis.to - ranges.yaxis.from < 0.00001) {
                ranges.yaxis.to = ranges.yaxis.from + 0.00001;
            }
            // do the zooming
            plotDetail = $.plot("#resultHolder", data,
                $.extend(true, {}, optionsDetail, {
                    xaxis: { min: ranges.xaxis.from, max: ranges.xaxis.to },
                    yaxis: { min: ranges.yaxis.from, max: ranges.yaxis.to },

                })
            );
            // don't fire event on the overview to prevent eternal loop

            overview.setSelection(ranges, true);
        });
            $("#resultOverview").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
            plotDetail.setSelection(ranges);
        }); 
        //connect the two until here


        plotAccordingToChoices();

        // add some hovering logic to each point...
             var previousPoint = null;
            $("#resultHolder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                $("#x").text(pos.x);
                $("#y").text(pos.y);
                if ($("#resultTooltipEnable:checked").length > 0) {
                    if (item) {
                        if (previousPoint != item.datapoint) {
                            previousPoint = item.datapoint;
                            $("#tooltip").remove();
                            var x = item.datapoint[0], y = item.datapoint[1];
                            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + " at " +x +" ns"+ " is " + y);
                        }
                    } 
                    else {
                        $("#tooltip").remove();
                        previousPoint = null;            
                    }
            } });

            // show the tooltip
            function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
                $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    display: 'none',
                    top: y - 35,
                    left: x + 5,
                    border: '1px solid #fdd',
                    padding: '2px',
                    'background-color': '#fee',
                    opacity: 0.80
                }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
            }
            // Tooltips code until here

        });
    }
});
```

can any one please point out the error i am making...

Comment: Could you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for your problem?

Comment: As @Raidri says, fiddle please, that's a straight up wall of code...

Comment: @Raidri how do i add flot plugins in fiddle can you please explain as i am new to fiddle. if do it in in javascript text area or external sources then how do i separate files. as in my html i need several JavaScript files. furthermore i am reading data from a json file.so how di i add every saperate file in fiddle. please help

Comment: You have to add the plugin under External Resources by inserting a URL to the js file.

Comment: @Raidri please find the fiddle here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sky6s/2/) sorry for the late reply. here you can see it only zooms the first graph not the second one. from the check box you can only select the second one and see nothing happens.

Comment: at line 150 in the javascript code if you add the commented line, then when both graphs are selected, both zooms. but then if only one of them is selected from check boxes,then none of them is zoomed. similarly if you comment 149, but not 150 then it works for only second graph. it seems i have to specify the axis. i want a generic solution so that it works for every combination of check boxes. my number of y-axis can go upto 4 but x- axis will always be one. @Mark you can also see the fiddle and see if you could help. thank you both of you in advance

Comment: updated link with commented line at line 150 [updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/sky6s/4/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is wrong there. Maybe it is something along the line "when you only show one graph, you don't have `y2axis`", but you have to debug that for yourself.

Comment: @Raidri you are right it seems so. but i think this all thing should be handled by selection plugin, it seems its an error in the selection plugin that we have to hard code number of axes it does not detects automatically.so if the number of axis changes it does nothing. right now the solution which i used is to use navigation plugin, using that every thing works fine. but the selection method is more preferable to me. anyways thanks for you help. if you find some solution then please tell me.